# Docker duplicates UDP packets

Tags: networking, docker, udp, netcat

I'm doing a very basic test with Docker in UDP.
I start a container on port 8000/UDP:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000/udp jgkamat/netcat -l -u -p 8000
```

I watch the traffic coming to this port:

```
ngrep -W byline -d any portrange 8000
```

I send an UDP packet:

```
nc -u <ip-address> 8000
```

This is the result of ngrep:

```
filter: (ip or ip6) and ( portrange 8000 )
#
U <my-public-ip>:37704 -> 192.168.0.4:8000
  hello.............
#
U <my-public-ip>:37704 -> 172.17.0.2:8000
  hello.
#
U <my-public-ip>:37704 -> 172.17.0.2:8000
  hello.
```

Can anyone please explain why packets are duplicated?

Answer (score -1):

You are seeing the transit of the same udp package, which is being forwarded:

```
netcat -(hello)-> host-interface -(hello)-> container-interface
```

Each container has its own network interface. `ngrep` is watching both host-interfaces: the one that is usually `eth0` and the one that is in the docker network, usually `docker0`.

Comment: This is true for the first two packets. What can we say about the third?

Comment: No, my program see same packet twice